# How to access subscriber Org static resource from Managed Package?

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, static-resources, subscriber

We have below line in a VisualForce page.

```
<apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource[customLogo]}" />
```

**CustomLogo** is read from Custom settings (Name of the static resource). This works perfect in Managed Package Development.

Once installed in a subscriber org, it's giving error,

> Static Resource named **testimage** does not exist. Check spelling

But it does exist, when you create a VF page (below) with same code, it runs with no error.

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource['testimage']}" />
</apex:page>
```

Any thoughts why this is happening? and any workarounds to fix this please. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Once the pkg is installed have you entered the values in your `Custom Setting`?

Comment: @RCS yes, entered value is 'testimage' and it's in the error message as well, it looks like it cannot find the static resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Visualforce pages run in their own namespace'd context, so by default, that's what you'll get, resources in your own package (even static resources, pages, etc). The only solution I can think of immediately would be to use the resource URL instead:

```
<apex:image value="{!resourceUrl}" />
```

Where resourceUrl would be something like:

```
/resource/testimage
```

If you do this, you'll have to reference your own static resources using the namespace convention:

```
/resource/yourns__testimage
```